# ...1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- streamio-ffmpeg (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I want to use FFMPEG to convert some MP3 files to OGG files. I used the following command in terminal:

```
sudo gem install streamio-ffmpeg
```

And after that, tried running this script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'streamio-ffmpeg'

movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new("path/to/movie.mov")

movie.duration # 7.5 (duration of the movie in seconds)
movie.bitrate # 481 (bitrate in kb/s)
movie.size # 455546 (filesize in bytes)

movie.video_stream # "h264, yuv420p, 640x480 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 371 kb/s, 16.75 fps, 15 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc" (raw video stream info)
movie.video_codec # "h264"
movie.colorspace # "yuv420p"
movie.resolution # "640x480"
movie.width # 640 (width of the movie in pixels)
movie.height # 480 (height of the movie in pixels)
movie.frame_rate # 16.72 (frames per second)

movie.audio_stream # "aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 75 kb/s" (raw audio stream info)
movie.audio_codec # "aac"
movie.audio_sample_rate # 44100
movie.audio_channels # 2

movie.valid? # true (would be false if ffmpeg fails to read the movie)
```

---

But I receive this error in the terminal window:

```
sergio@mint-vm ~/Documents/audio-convert $ ruby demo.rb
/home/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- streamio-ffmpeg (LoadError)
    from /home/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from demo.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

This is not a rails application, just a plain old Ruby script I intend to use from the command line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes ffmpeg is installed and working correctly. I demo'd it using this gist: https://gist.github.com/975354

Comment: Could it be because I used `sudo gem install` instead of `gem install`? I just tried installing another completely unrelated gem without using sudo and that library works completely fine as expected.

Comment: both answers are right on skipping the `sudo` it basically vanishes all the environment and make `gem` forget about rvm. but I like @user1083138 answer more as it shows the full path for getting it working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try creating and appling a new RVM gemset with:

```
rvm use 1.9.3@ffmpegnewgemset --create
```

then **do** install streamio-ffmpeg gem with:

```
gem install streamio-ffmpeg
```

then just run it as:

```
ruby demo.rb
```

(*Make sure you are already inside folder with your script as changing folders with 'cd' may change you active RVM gemset.*)

Answer (score 1):

I see you use rvm. Be sure, when you used the `sudo gem install streamio-ffmpeg` then your rvm used the same version what you use when you ran the script.

Try to install it without sudo too, and run the demo.rb exactly after installing gem in the same terminal...

`gem install streamio-ffmpeg && ruby demo.rb`